# Sorting a list based on nested list

Tags: c#

I have two c# classes - Topics and Subscriptions.

Topics:

```
    public class Topics
{
    public string TopicName { get; set; }
    public List<Subscriptions> Subscriptions { get; set; }

}
```

Subscriptions:

```
    public class Subscriptions
{
    public string SubscriptionName { get; set; }
    public string MessageCount { get; set; }

}
```

These classes pull data from an azure bus and count the messages on each subscription.

I have this data output to a table and have put in a filter to sort the table based on the filter.  I've managed to get a lot of the sort working but I can't get it to work when trying to order anything in the table by anything in the Subscriptions class.  I'm trying to do this with a switch:

```
    public List<Models.Topics> TopicsList { get; set; }
    public List<Models.Topics> Topics { get; set; } 
public List<Models.Subscriptions> Subscriptions { get; set; }

        public subCounterModel()
    {
        Topics = ad.GetSubscriptionData();
        list = val.getListVaules();
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
switch (filter)
            {
                case "1": //Topic Name - ascending
                        TopicsList = Topics
                            .OrderBy(t => t.TopicName)
                            .Skip((P - 1) * S)
                            .Take(S)
                            .ToList();
                    break;
                case "2": //Topic Name - Descending
                        TopicsList = Topics
                            .OrderByDescending(t => t.TopicName)
                            .Skip((P - 1) * S)
                            .Take(S)
                            .ToList();
                    break;
                case "3": //Subscription Name - Ascending
                        TopicsList = Topics
                            .OrderBy(t => t.Subscriptions.Min(s => s.SubscriptionName))
                            .Skip((P - 1) * S)
                            .Take(S)
                            .ToList();
                    break;
                case "4": //Subscription Name - Descending
                        TopicsList = Topics
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Subscriptions.Min(m => m.SubscriptionName))
                            .Skip((P - 1) * S)
                            .Take(S)
                            .ToList();
                    break;
                case "5": // Message Count - Ascending
                        TopicsList = Topics
                            .OrderBy(t => t.Subscriptions.Min(s => s.MessageCount))
                            .Skip((P - 1) * S)
                            .Take(S)
                            .ToList();
                    break;
                case "6": //Message Count - Descending
                        TopicsList = Topics
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Subscriptions.Min(m => m.MessageCount))
                            .Skip((P - 1) * S)
                            .Take(S)
                            .ToList();
                    break;
            }
}
```

Case 1 and 2 work as expected, however 3 - 6 do not work as i intended.  This works in a sense that it sorts the objects by message count but it doesnt sort the outer layer properly.  How can i rework this so I can sort this by messagecount and subscriptionname?

Example:

Selecting the filter "Message Count - Ascending" passes the string value of "5" to my switch.  This runs.  What it seems like is happening is it will sort each topic by subscription and then list those topics in order.  So if I have a topic called "Topic1" with 15 subscriptions in it, those 15 appears to be correctly sorted, but it will then put (a correctly sorted) "Topic2" below topic 1 instead of doing a "Merge" of the results on the table.  I think what I need to do is create a new Topic object for every instance of where a topic has more than 1 subscription and then sort by that but i'm unsure how this would be done in a lambda query.

[image]

Here is an example of me sorting by Subscription name.  Redacted some data for privacy reasons.  It correctly sorts the topics, but doesn't order as I expect.

Comment: Some examples of what the input is, what you expect to happen, and what's actually happening would be extremely helpful.

Comment: In using `Min` aren't you just selecting the same item from the collection every time therefore just sorting by the collection order?

Comment: In case of `Descending` you should be using `Max`. I guess your code should be working for `3` & `5`.

Comment: @John I have included a small text example and a screenshot of some output.

Comment: @Karan 3 & 5 "Work" in the sense that it sorts the subscriptions inside of the topics and then writes that, but i want it to "Merge" the topics and then write that to the table.  I have included screenshot example in my post.

Comment: It seems like you want to flatten some objects into a single list - but I'm still confused when you say "I have this data output to a table". Is the data in a table, or are you talking about a `List<T>` or some list type? Is the data held in the objects you've provided definitions for in a list or `IEnumerable`? e.g. `List<Topics>` or something of that nature? I'm trying to read between the lines because you've not provided enough information yet but it sounds like you just want to use union/project to select the data into the structure you want. We don't know what `TopicsList` represents.

Comment: @Charleh Sorry my question still isn't clear, i've updated it a bit further with some more code to hopefully clarify.  

This is a website so when i say table i literally mean a HTML table that i'm passing the TopicsList to using a foreach loop.  The data for this Topics List comes from a json string that i'm storing in a azure blob.  This is gathered on the page load using Topics = ad.GetSubscriptionData();.  I believe that flattening the list is what I need to do but I have tried to do this with .SelectMany but i couldn't work out how to produce a result. Hopefully that is a bit clearer!

Comment: Right, so am I to take it that you want your sort on subscription name for example to happen across the whole table, i.e. you don't want to have the subscription sorted inside each group, you want the whole lot in subscription name order?

Comment: @Charleh Exactly that! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is flatten the subscriptions and then sort.

That would look something like this:

```
var subsTopics = Topics.SelectMany(t => t.Subscriptions, (topic, sub) => new { topic.TopicName, sub.MessageCount, sub.SubscriptionName });
```

You can then chuck your `OrderBy` on the end of this:

```
subsTopics.OrderBy(o => o.SubscriptionName);
```

`SelectMany` when provided with many `IEnumerables` will combine them into a single sequence - there are a few overloads and one allows you to provide a transformation function (which I've provided a lambda expression for).